# Eloquent collection column select as + remove spacing

Tags: eloquent

Let's say I have the following Eloquent query:

```
DB::table('table')
        ->select('first_name', 'insertion', 'last_name')
        ->get();
```

Would there be a way to implement the following (pseudo):

SELECT 'first_name', 'insertion', 'last_name' AS 'name' FROM table WHERE name = $query (all spaces trimmed so that Heinz von Walsmit would become "HeinzvonWalsmit" for example.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MySQL:

```
DB::table('table')
    ->selectRaw('CONCAT(`first_name`, `insertion`, `last_name`) as `name`')
    ->get();
```

Comment: The problem is that my employer wants to simply use Eloquent and not raw queries.

Comment: There's no built-in method for that, you have to use `selectRaw()`. I assume you need the string in the query and can't build it after executing the query?

Comment: Sadly not. I simply pass the string to the controller from where it enters this logic. I indeed have it working with a selectRaw but I guess I will need to explain that raw will be nessecary.